Which ACC Webhook to know when newly published Revit model will have it's ElementGroup data available to be fetched from AEC DataModel API
I'm using Revit 2025 and I'm trying to automate the usage of GraphQL-based AEC Data Model API, by pulling latest Element data from ElementGroups (.rvt design files) as soon as a new version of Revit model is published to ACC. (Ref. AEC Data Model construct). I recieve the dm.version.added Event in my callback when a new version of design file is added.
However, as the new version of .rvt design file is published and processing is in progress on ACC, AEC Data Model API does not get the latest data immediately after dm.version.added event is received in my callback, and therefore, fetches the old version's Element data. After I wait for a while, AEC Data Model fetches the new version and newly published Element data inside it. But the .rvt design file is still shown as processing on ACC at this point of time.
So I'm not sure how long do I wait to fetch the latest published Element data. Is there an ACC Webhook which will let me know that the newly published Revit design file is "processed enough" by ACC for me to fetch the latest Element data (Rooms, Walls, etc.) from AEC Data Model API?
I found the model derivative webhook event: extraction.finished but I don't think this is what I should be doing. As I do not have a Workflow ID of any jobs to begin with, the extraction happens automatically as a new design file is published from Revit 2025.

The extraction to AEC Data Model may take some time depending with the type/complexity of the model. You may opt to manually poll the status of the extraction process and until it is successful usng the elementGroupExtractionStatus query
See more on : https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/aecdatamodel/v1/developers_guide/faq/
